# How to express backpropagation dE/dV using matrix

Tags: neural-networks, matrix, backpropagation, derivative

I'm new in NN and my math is not that good. I try to do manual calculation using NN model. I already know and try to calculate the feedforward and backward one by one using the formula. but when I try to calculate the backpropagation in matrix form, I am confused how to write it, especially in dE/dV. I have NN with architecture like this:

[image]

Input, weight and bias is like this:

[image]

if the formula of dE/dV given as below:

[image]

what I want to ask is, how to apply this formula to get a dE/dV matrix like the one below?

[image]

I'm confused because if I calculate one dE/dV, for example dE/dV11, I can directly enter the wjk matrix and zj matrix, but for xi, I only have to enter x1 while the xi matrix consists of x1, x2, and x3.

Comment: This site supports math typesetting using MathJax. This will make your equations more legible and help people who use screen readers. Questions that use math typesetting are also more likely to be understood & get useful answers. More infomration: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

> I can directly enter the wjk matrix and zj matrix, but for xi, I only have to enter x1 while the xi matrix consists of x1, x2, and x3.

$W_{jk}$ is not a matrix, it's a real number whose value determined by the connection between $j$-th neuron in the last hidden layer and the $k$-th neuron in the output layer in the shape you gave.

For the matrix shape, it depends on the [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) you assume (i.e. numerator or denominator). Either is fine, you just need to be consistent across the calculations. The one you assumed is denominator layout. Its transpose is the numerator layout.

You can then substitute the individual values you've found to the matrix.